# Refresh token permissions in Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have been looking everywhere, but I cannot find any specific information.

according to the latest SDK 3.0 documentation
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/AccessToken#getPermissions:

the list of permissions returned by AccessToken.getPermissions() "may be **outdated** if permissions have been added or removed since the time the AccessToken object was created"

my question is:
is there any way to ask for a **refresh of the list of permissions**, so that the token can reflect the up-to-date list of permissions kept by Facebook?

Answer (score 3):

Since Facebook SDK version 3.14, Facebook added the refreshPermissions method to the Session class.

For more info you can check the source code in github: 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/f6c4e4c1062bcc74e5a25b3243f6bee2e32d949e/facebook/src/com/facebook/Session.java#L605

Answer (score 0):

FOUND THE SOLUTION FOR MY NEEDS:

instead of updating my token, I just make an FQL query to retrieve the remote (up-to-date) status of the permissions I want to know about

the following code queries about publish permissions (officially called "publish_actions"):

```
public void asyncQueryIfHasPublishPermissions() {
    String fqlQuery = "SELECT publish_actions FROM permissions WHERE uid = me()";
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Request request = new Request(session,
            "/fql",                         
            params,                         
            HttpMethod.GET,                 
            new Request.Callback(){         
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                    boolean publishPermissions = false;
                    try {
                        if (graphResponse.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getInt("publish_actions")==1) {
                            publishPermissions = true;
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("FacebookIntegration", "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Log.e("FacebookIntegration", "FacebookRequestError "+ error.getErrorMessage());
                    }
                    Log.i("FacebookIntegration", "asyncQueryIfHasPublishPermissions response: "+publishPermissions);
                }                  
        }); 
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
}
```

Comment: But how do we make the Session object reflect the updated permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by Daniele B looks kind of scary, so I decided to write my own.

It is not the actual solution, because it doesn't upgrade the permission stored in the `Session` object, but it allows us to check which permissions are given to us.

```
    Request.executeGraphPathRequestAsync(facebookSession, "me/permissions", new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        GraphObject graphObject; 

        List<String> permissionsToGet = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
        if (response != null && (graphObject = response.getGraphObject()) != null){
            JSONObject permissions = (JSONObject) ((JSONArray) graphObject.getProperty("data")).get(0);
            for (String permission : facebookPermissions){
                if (!permissions.has(permission) || permissions.getInt(permission) != 1){
                    permissionsToGet.add(permission);
                }
            }

            if (!permissionsToGet.isEmpty()){
                //get new permissions
            } else {
                //all needed permissions are available
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception ex){
            //handle error
        }

    }
});
```